# Excel: Formula to find most common text between dates

Tags: excel, function, text, formula

I have a spreadsheet where data is arranged by multiple categories: date, location, and ID code. I need to figure out a way to show the most common ID between two dates at a specific location.

I've tried following advice from before, and this is what I have:

```
=INDEX(CodeRange,MATCH(MAX(FREQUENCY(IF((DateRange>=A4)*(DateRange<A5),COUNTIFS(CodeRange,">"&CodeRange,AssetRange,$B$1),""),COUNTIFS(CodeRange,">"&CodeRange,AssetRange,$B$1))),FREQUENCY(IF((DateRange>=A4)*(DateRange<A5),COUNTIFS(CodeRange,">"&CodeRange,AssetRange,$B$1),""),COUNTIFS(CodeRange,">"&CodeRange,AssetRange,$B$1)),0))
```

Names: CodeRange is the ID column, DateRange is the date column, and AssetRange is the location column. A4 and A5 contain the two dates, and $B$1 refers to the cell which contains the name of the location

However, this formula returns the incorrect ID when I tested it on a smaller data sample. I've made sure to enter control+shift+enter and I'm not familiar with the frequency function so I suspect that's where the problem is.

Please advise in any way you can, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lack of sample data forces me to assume that the ID Code is a numeric value. If this is correct then either the [MODE function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MODE-function-E45192CE-9122-4980-82ED-4BDC34973120), [MODE.SNGL function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MODE-SNGL-function-f1267c16-66c6-4386-959f-8fba5f8bb7f8) or [MODE.MULT function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MODE-MULT-function-50FD9464-B2BA-4191-B57A-39446689AE8C) should be appropriate. Array processing of dated conditions similar to what you applied to the [FREQUENCY function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/FREQUENCY-function-44E3BE2B-ECA0-42CD-A3F7-FD9EA898FDB9) will provide dated criteria.

[image: MODE.SNGL MODE.MULT dated array formula]

The array formula in H15 uses MODE.SNGL.

```
=MODE.SNGL(IF(A2:A25>=F15, IF(A2:A25<=G15, C2:C25)))
```

Array formulas need to be finalized with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter↵</kbd>.
Try and reduce your full-column references to ranges more closely representing the extents of your actual data. Array formulas chew up calculation cycles logarithmically so it is good practise to narrow the referenced ranges to a minimum.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to implement this now